# Permissions for Voice search

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-permissions

Running [Google Voice Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch) on my ICS (Android 4.0.4) tablet yields strange behavior with the following warnings:

```
W/PackageManager( 1571): Unknown permission com.google.android.voicesearch.SHORTCUTS_ACCESS in package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
W/PackageManager( 1571): Unknown permission com.google.android.voicesearch.AUDIO_FILE_ACCESS in package com.google.android.gm
W/RecognitionManagerService( 1571): no available voice recognition services found
I/ActivityManager( 1571): Start proc com.android.voicedialer for broadcast com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver: pid=2130 uid=10033 gids={3002}
I/ActivityManager( 1571): No longer want com.android.voicedialer (pid 2130): hidden #16
I/ActivityManager( 1571): Force stopping package com.google.android.voicesearch uid=10074
W/PackageManager( 1571): Unknown permission com.google.android.apps.googlevoice.permission.AUTO_SEND in package com.google.android.voicesearch
D/BackupManagerService( 1571): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.google.android.voicesearch flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
```

Curious to understand why, I looked up the [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) list but I couldn't find any mention to:

- SHORTCUTS_ACCESS
- AUDIO_FILE_ACCESS
- AUTO_SEND

What are these permissions and where I can learn more about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These permissions are defined inside of the Voice Search APK and GMail APK. They are private permissions, protected by APK signature.

They are used to restrict access to internal application data and private Intent targets, and are not intended to be user visible.

Comment: Thanks +1 for shedding some light on this. Any idea **why I am receiving these warnings?** After all, I don't see these warnings on other devices (when using Google Voice Search)