# How to use the permission "com.google.android.voicesearch.SHORTCUTS_ACCESS" in voice search?

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I use the `voicesearch` in my phone, it cannot open the webpage automatically, and it shows me the logs as follows:

> Package com.android.quicksearchbox wants to handle GLOBAL_SEARCH, but
>   does not have permission
>   com.google.android.voicesearch.SHORTCUTS_ACCESS No global search
>   activity found

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041396/permissions-for-voice-search. This should help.